# ¿Cómo actualizar Angular "4.3.6" a "4.4.4" y Angular Material "2.0.0-beta.10" a "2.0.0-beta.11"?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

Actualmente estoy trabajando con **Angular CLI 1.3.2**, **Angular 4.3.6** y **Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.10**, y como sabrán hace unos días lanzaron nuevas versiones: **Angular CLI 1.4.3**, **Angular 4.4.4** y **Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.11**. Mis preguntas son... ¿Cómo puedo actualizar a las versiones ya mencionadas?, ¿hay algún comando que haga todo el proceso?, ¿debo actualizar el "package.json" manualmente y luego hacer un "npm install" o qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) para actualizar tu `package.json`.

**Paso #1** instalar npm-check-updates global:

```
~$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

**Paso #2** Ejecuta y comprueba tu `package.json` del proyecto:

```
carpetaProyecto$ ncu
```

Esto te puede dar un resultado como esto:

```
express           4.12.x  →   4.13.x
multer            ^0.1.8  →   ^1.0.1
react-bootstrap  ^0.22.6  →  ^0.24.0
react-a11y        ^0.1.1  →   ^0.2.6
webpack          ~1.9.10  →  ~1.10.5
```

**Paso #3** Ejecutar con `-u` para actualizar tu `package.json`:

```
carpetaProyecto$ ncu -u
```

**Paso #4** Actualizar los paquetes (`packages`)

```
~$ npm update
```

---

También funciona con [`bower`](https://bower.io/) para actualizar `bower.json`

```
carpetaProyecto$ ncu -m bower
```

Ejecutar con `-u` para actualizar tu `bower.json`:

```
carpetaProyecto$ ncu -m bower -u
```

Comment: ¿Luego de hacer esto debo ejecutar **npm install** o lo actualiza automáticamente?

Comment: @adrianojosue - Simplemente con `npm update`

Comment: Ok, gracias por ayudarme. Una última pregunta: al ejecutar **ncu -u** sólo me actualizo las dependencias de desarrollador, luego decía algo (que no recuerdo porque limpié la terminal lol) sobre **ncu -a**, al ejecutarlo si me actualizo las dependencias, ¿está bien que actualizara el package.json así?

Comment: @adrianojosue - Me alegro.. y si... el flag `-a` es para actualizar aquellas dependencias cuyas últimas versión satisface la dependencia [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning) -- [Ver todas las flags de npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates#advanced-options)

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias formas de hacerlo, una es modificar la versión en el archivo package.json y correr el comando npm install.

La segunda puedes usar el siguiente comando:

```
npm upgrade -save [NombreDelPaquete]
```

Otra es con este comando:

```
npm install [NombreDelPaquete]@latest
```

En caso de Angular y Angular CLI debes hacerlo también agregando "-g" para que se instale también de manera global en tu PC, así los nuevos proyectos que crees tendrán esta última versión.

En caso de Angular CLI, para evitar errores lo recomendable es correr los siguientes comandos desde la consola:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**NOTA:** Cuidado al actualizar porque algunas funciones de tu aplicación pueden ser incompatibles y dejarán de funcionar.